# Identifying this kind of combinatoric permutation

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, permutations

I feel kind of silly asking this, but I am having a hard time identifying what this exactly called. I'm specifically trying to find the wiki page on it and could not find it on this list of permutation topics [wiki page.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_permutation_topics)

What type of combinatorics (or permutations?) is this?

We have multiple sets:

```
(1, 2)
(a, b, c)
(foo, bar)
```

With these sets, we are to generate the following combinations:

```
(1, a, foo)
(1, a, bar)
(1, b, foo)
(1, b, bar)
(1, c, foo)
(1, c, bar)

(2, a, foo)
(2, a, bar)
(2, b, foo)
(2, b, bar)
(2, c, foo)
(2, c, bar)
```

Note the total number of combinations is just the number of elements in each set multiplied together (2x3x2).

A link to a wiki article would be ideal.

Comment: A Cartesian product of sets?

Comment: @hardmath is correct. If we were to denote the set $\{1,2\}$ by $N$ for numbers, $\{a,b,c\}$ by $L$ for letters, and $\{$foo, bar$\}$ by $W$ for words, what you describe is the cartesian product denoted as $N\times L\times W$ which creates an ordered triple (pair in the case of 2 sets or n-tuple in the case of arbitrary number of sets) $\{(n,l,w): n\in N, l\in L, w\in W\}$.  Officially a "permutation" would refer to a rearrangement of elements in an ordered set, but would still use all of the elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer was a [Cartesian product of sets.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)

Special thanks to user hardmath, for providing the answer in the comments.

Comment: Thank you for supplying an answer, getting this off the Unanswered list.